# Accessing multiple controllers in view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, selector

I have a view im making that will comprise of functionality thats already laid out in 2 different controllers. Sort of a hybrid.

I wondered how I handle this approach structurally? as the existing views use selectors and a couple of delegates to send to their controller, however the new view would ideally want access to a couple of controllers functions. So I cant just fire selectors to the controllers as it isnt connected to just one? (to be able to use self.viewController)

For example a current view feature uses:

```
[self.viewController performSelector:@selector(getParBusFader:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:_busOffset - 1]];
```

Where as if i wanted to access this from my new view I cant use self.viewController as it has a different controller its getting other features from.

Any solutions here so I can send different elements of the view to different controllers and prevent duplication?

Can i just instantiate an instance of the controller locally and access it that way?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Read up on Container and Child View Controllers. You can add multiple "Children" if you want. When using Interface Builder, you can add a `UIContainerView` object and it handles the setup for you.

Here's a very simple example:

```
//
//  QuickTestViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "FirstChildViewController.h"

@interface QuickTestViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) FirstChildViewController *fcVC;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  QuickTestViewController.m
//

#import "QuickTestViewController.h"

@interface QuickTestViewController ()

@end

@implementation QuickTestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // instantiate a FirstChildViewController
    _fcVC = [[FirstChildViewController alloc] init];

    // add it as a Child View Controller
    [self addChildViewController:_fcVC];

    // configure its view and add the view to self.view
    _fcVC.view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 50, 200, 100);
    _fcVC.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self.view addSubview:_fcVC.view];

    // tell FirstChildViewController we're finished adding it
    [_fcVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

}

- (IBAction)btnTapped:(id)sender {
    // call a method in FirstChildViewController
    [_fcVC performSelector:@selector(getParBusFader:) withObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:5]];
}

@end
```

---

```
//
//  FirstChildViewController.h
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface FirstChildViewController : UIViewController

- (void)getParBusFader:(NSNumber *)x;

@end
```

---

```
//
//  FirstChildViewController.m
//

#import "FirstChildViewController.h"

@interface FirstChildViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstChildViewController

- (void)getParBusFader:(NSNumber *)x {
    NSLog(@"passed value: %ld", (long)x.integerValue);
}

@end
```

---

Comment: Im working in code, no storyboards, your proposal is literally just put the other views in a parent view?

Comment: The only thing in this example related to storyboards was connecting a button to an action. Regardless... You can simply *instantiate* ViewControllers and call methods in them, or you can add them as Child View Controllers. Adding as a Child has some advantages, particularly if you are also adding that VC's view to you current view hierarchy.